# Is my JavaScript code correct?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, api

I am trying to get JSON out of my Rest API and want to use this JSON information to show them on my application. 
Is the function `renderUserState` ever called? Because the rest of my Code should work fine.

```
function testSubmit() {
    var card = getQueryVariable("select_card");
    var action = getQueryVariable("select_action");

    var urlGet = "/test/api/getting-ready?cardId=" + card + "&action=" + action;

    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : urlGet,
        dataType : 'json',
        encode : true
    }).done(renderUserState);
}

function renderUserState(userState){
    $("#gold").text(userState.goldAmount);
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the API response here?

Comment: If you ever call "testSubmit" then it should work? Code seems correct to my eye at least.

Comment: What does `encode : true` do?

Comment: Why don't you try ? Put a `console.log(userState)` inside the `rednerUserState` function and see if it is called.

Comment: @Weedoze have added it, thanks. Good idea

Comment: @CodeLover yes. I want to get an String ( In this String is data in JSON format ) and then I will use these vars to show them in my html.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, your code is correct you just need to call a function in the done since the done will receive the data returned by your endpoint.
Hope this will help you click on the button and see the log.

```js
function testSubmit() {

  //  var card = getQueryVariable("select_card");
  // var action = getQueryVariable("select_action");
  
//  var urlGet = "/test/api/getting-ready?cardId=" + card + "&action=" + action;
  var urlGetTest = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : urlGetTest,
        dataType : 'json',
        encode : true
    }).done((userState) => {
      renderUserState(userState);
      });
}

function renderUserState(userState){
    console.log(userState);
//    $("#gold").text(userState.goldAmount);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onClick="testSubmit();">Click Here</button>
```

Comment: Yeah let me know then

Comment: You think it should work with fresh generated JSON to? I try to explain what I think: On your link there ist a file with Stuff in JSON format, but if I call my Rest API it generates JSON and returns it to me.

Comment: Is there a differnce or is my Api broken? :D Because if call the api direct on its link I am getting JSON back..

Comment: https://imgur.com/hBbuq3A <-- my api response if you call the link directly

Comment: I have found my problem. I have to delete the tabs an stuff from my JSON return. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Cool that fine.